# So I am trying to create this json file using gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Here is the code I want to create with my Java code. I'm not doing anything elaborate. Just trying to refresh myself with parsing json from java.

```
[{"county":"Jefferson",
    "houses":\[
        {"squareFeet":1100,
        "bedrooms":2,
        "bathrooms":2,
        "internet":"y",
        "location":"Country"
        },
        {"squareFeet":750,
        "bedrooms":1,
        "bathrooms":1,
        "internet":"n",
        "location":"Town"
        }
    \]
}]
```

At the moment my Java code looks like this.

With this code below I am close to having it, with the exception of the first Object, and also the title to the array of houses.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.List;

public class HousesToJSON {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        JSONArray houses = new JSONArray();

        House houseOne = createHouseObjectOne();
        House houseTwo = createHouseObjectTwo();

        houses.add(houseOne);
        houses.add(houseTwo);

        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("houses.json")) {
            gson.toJson(houses, writer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static House createHouseObjectOne() {
        House house = new House();

        house.setSquareFeet(1100);
        house.setBedrooms(2);
        house.setBathrooms(2);
        house.setInternet('y');
        house.setLocation("Country");

        return house;
    }

    private static House createHouseObjectTwo() {
        House house = new House();

        house.setSquareFeet(750);
        house.setBedrooms(2);
        house.setBathrooms(1);
        house.setInternet('y');
        house.setLocation("Town");

        return house;
    }
}
```

This create the file below.

```
[
  {
    "squareFeet": 1100,
    "bedrooms": 2,
    "bathrooms": 2,
    "internet": "y",
    "location": "Country"
  },
  {
    "squareFeet": 750,
    "bedrooms": 2,
    "bathrooms": 1,
    "internet": "y",
    "location": "Town"
  }
]
```

I am still pretty new at this, and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What you want to generate is not a valid JSON, or you might have a typo there. Also, Google Gson and org.json are two different things that should not be mixed together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should provide you with the neccesary objects for your JSON example:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CountyContainer {

 @SerializedName("county")
 @Expose
 private String county;
 @SerializedName("houses")
 @Expose
 private List<House> houses = null;

 public String getCounty() {
  return county;
 }

 public void setCounty(String county) {
  this.county = county;
 }

 public List<House> getHouses() {
  return houses;
 }

 public void setHouses(List<House> houses) {
  this.houses = houses;
 }
}
```

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class House {

 @SerializedName("squareFeet")
 @Expose
 private Integer squareFeet;
 @SerializedName("bedrooms")
 @Expose
 private Integer bedrooms;
 @SerializedName("bathrooms")
 @Expose
 private Integer bathrooms;
 @SerializedName("internet")
 @Expose
 private String internet;
 @SerializedName("location")
 @Expose
 private String location;

 public Integer getSquareFeet() {
  return squareFeet;
 }

 public void setSquareFeet(Integer squareFeet) {
  this.squareFeet = squareFeet;
 }

 public Integer getBedrooms() {
  return bedrooms;
 }

 public void setBedrooms(Integer bedrooms) {
  this.bedrooms = bedrooms;
 }

 public Integer getBathrooms() {
  return bathrooms;
 }

 public void setBathrooms(Integer bathrooms) {
  this.bathrooms = bathrooms;
 }

 public String getInternet() {
  return internet;
 }

 public void setInternet(String internet) {
  this.internet = internet;
 }

 public String getLocation() {
  return location;
 }

 public void setLocation(String location) {
  this.location = location;
 }
}
```

You can generate these yourself using this online service and selecting the GSON annotation style:
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

When you've created your objects, you can write those objects to a JSON file using:

```
final Gson gson = new Gson();
try (final FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("houses.json")) {
 gson.toJson(houses, writer); // houses refers to your object containing the List of House objects and the country
} catch (final IOException e) {
 // Handle exceptions here
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use place the JSON data into a `String`:

```
String json = gson.toJson(houses);
```

For more information regarding GSON functionality, please take a look at the official documentation:
https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/module-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no `House` class provided, but I guess we can skip it. You are moving in the right direction. Just add another class:

```
public class County {
    private String county;
    private List<House> houses;

    // getters, setters, whatever :) 
}
```

And create instance of this class. Set name (county field) and houses and serialize to JSON :)

I would probably rename json array to `JSONArray counties = new JSONArray();` and what you need to add to this array is some county with name "Jefferson" and list of houses that you have now.

```
County county = new County();
county.setCounty("Jefferson");

List<House> houses = new ArrayList<>();
houses.add(houseOne);
houses.add(houseTwo);

county.setHouses(houses);

counties.add(county);
```

This might not be 100% working code, but hope the idea is clear :)